# W3C Validation error: general entity "gid" not defined and no default entity

Tags: html, w3c

This error has something to do with the link of Linedin.com
I have included the social network links in a PHP include (social-icons.php) and when I try to use HTML standard character like &amp it doesn't change the validation.
Here is the validation errors on W3C: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://sneakyrascal.com/theyeastdiet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually if you change all the `&` with `&amp;` the website will be validated. Please note the `;` after `&amp` (in your example you **didn't** write it).

Answer (score 0):

You've got an & literal in your markup.  As & has special meaning in HTML you need to escape it with &